# Distance between point to list of points

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the distance from point `p` to each of the points in list `s`.

```py
import math
s= [(1,4),(4,2),(6,3)]
p= (3,7)

p0,p1=p
dist=[]

for s0,s1 in s:
    dist=math.sqrt((p0[0] - p1[0])**2 + (s0[1] - s1[1])**2)
    dist= dist+1
    print(dist)
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-77e000c3374a> in <module>
      3 dist=[]
      4 for s0,s1 in s:
----> 5    dist=math.sqrt((p0[0] - p1[0])**2 + (s0[1] - s1[1])**2)
      6 
      7 

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I see that accessing the location is ceased as `p0,p1` are `int`s. but in this scenario I'm not getting an idea how to address this.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: You are indexing an integer, which is not possible (`p0[0]`)

Comment: Others have addressed the most pressing concerns of your code.  There remains a few mysteries; what is `dist=[]` and why are you adding 1 to your computed distance with `dist = dist+1`.   You may want to just remove those two lines of code.  Or maybe you were trying to do something more, like add each distance to a list so you ended up with a single result instead of just printing each distance?

Comment: @Steve yes, your right dist=dist+1 doesn't make sense. But dist=[ ] is needed I believe as we are storing results in a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accidentally using indexing on your data even though you already separated your points into `x, y`. In addition, you are overwriting your list and not saving the data. Also the distance formula is incorrect it should be a subtraction between points not addition. Try this:

```
import math
s= [(1,4),(4,2),(6,3)]
p= (3,7)

p0,p1=p
dist=[]

for s0,s1 in s:
    dist_=math.sqrt((p0 - s0)**2 + (p1 - s1)**2) #Edit this line to [0]s and [1]s
    dist_= dist_+1 #Also change name and/or delete
#    print(dist)
    dist.append(dist_) #Save data to list
```

Comment: Ha!  You addressed each of my questions to the OPs question by updating your answer.  Great!

Comment: Overtime I fixed one thing, I found something else wrong lol.

Comment: Check out math.hypot(). Saves you from the work of having to implement it yourself, *and* might give better precision in some nasty cases.

Answer (score 2):

`dist=math.sqrt((p0[0] - p1[0])**2 + (s0[1] - s1[1])**2)`

Here, you are indexing integer.

Moreover, you've made **mistake in calculation**. It should be:

`dist=math.sqrt((p0 - s0)**2 + (p1 - s1)**2)`

Answer (score 2):

If what is desired is a list of the distances, that can be done in a single line of code with a list comprehension:

```
import math
import pprint

s = [(1,2),(3,4),(-1,1),(6,-7),(0, 6),(-5,-8),(-1,-1),(6,0),(1,-1)]
p = (3,-4)

dists = [math.sqrt((p[0]-s0)**2 + (p[1]-s1)**2) for s0, s1 in s]

pprint.pprint(dists)
```

The other thing here is that I've removed the `dist = dist + 1` from the OPs code.  I don't see that being correct...why add 1 to each computed distance?

Result:

```
[6.324555320336759,
 8.0,
 6.4031242374328485,
 4.242640687119285,
 10.44030650891055,
 8.94427190999916,
 5.0,
 5.0,
 3.605551275463989]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to change this line:

```
    dist=math.sqrt((p0[0] - p1[0])**2 + (s0[1] - s1[1])**2)
```

To:

```
    dist=math.sqrt((p0 - p1)**2 + (s0 - s1)**2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the Euclidean distance, you could do something like this (even without `import math`)

```
s = [(1, 4), (4, 2), (6, 3)]
p = (3, 7)

for point in s:
    sum_ = sum((p[i] - point[i]) ** 2 for i in range(len(p)))
    distance = sum_ ** (1 / 2)  # take the square root, the same thing as math.sqrt()
    print(p, point, round(distance, 1))
```

Results:

```py
(3, 7) (1, 4) 3.6
(3, 7) (4, 2) 5.1
(3, 7) (6, 3) 5.0
```

The error you get in your code is because you used indexing on an integer. Just like doing this:

```py
>>> a = 3
>>> a[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    a[0]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not constrained by the packages you can use. An implementation using NumPy would be more swift.

```
import numpy as np

s = np.array([(1,4),(4,2),(6,3)])
p = np.array((3,7))

dist = np.linalg.norm(p - s, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
array([3.60555128, 5.09901951, 5.])
```